# Спойлерить сюжет

Tags: выбор-слов, словосочетания

[См.](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80) первое значение слова (с пометкой ***неол.***). Словосочетание *спойлерить сюжет* корректно с точки зрения правил? Мне кажется, это плеоназм, но люди так всё-таки говорят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, *спойлер* это не сюжет, а некая информация о сюжете, которая может испортить читателю/зрителю/игроку всё удовольствие от книги/фильма/ компьютерной игры. Допустим, сюжет такой: **В загородный дом мадам N. приглашены гости. Во время застолья один из гостей умирает. Врач констатирует смерть от цианида. Прибывший на место убийства дедектив проводит расследование и находит убийцу**. А *спойлером* в данном случае может быть **убийцей оказалась дочь мадам N.** *Спойлер*, повторюсь, это не сюжет, а только ключевая информация о сюжете. Поэтому выражение *спойлерить сюжет* представляется мне имеющим право на существование (если уж так всё равно говорят), и оно не является плеоназмом, на мой взгляд.

Comment: Дело ведь в том, что проспойлерить можно только сюжет. Здесь очевидно, что слово *сюжет* просто-напросто излишнее.

Comment: Пахать (в первоначальном смысле) можно только землю, но говорят ведь не просто "крестьянин пашет", а "крестьянин пашет землю". Просто "спойлерит" у нас прижиться не может. Нам нужно что-то "спойлерить".

Answer (score 3):

(Изменил ответ в соответствии с выясненным контекстом.)

К способу словообразования трудно придраться: мусор - мусорить, спойлер - спойлерить. Другое дело - не обойти ли в переводе столь неудобопроизносимое слово?

**P.S.** А можно и на словообразование посмотреть иначе. Спойлер (то, чем мусорят) - слово, образованное от глагола to spoil добавлением суффикса -er, характерного для производителя действия, т.е. "спойлер" здесь - "нечто производящее порчу". Но поскольку это нечто производит действие глагола to spoil, то зачем глагол образовывать с суффиксом отглагольного существительного? Тогда уж "спойлить", и опять возникает вопрос: почему без этого слова не перевести?

Comment: Поместить под спойлер? Вы о чём? Я про первое значение.

Comment: Ну а в таком контексте это вообще не имеет отношения к терминологии. Это неоправданное использование непереведённого глагола to spoil в банальном значении "испортить". То же самое, что называть людей "пиплами", "юзать" что-то и т. п.

Comment: Как бы то ни было, в русском языке оно уже прижилось. А вы лучше на мой вопрос ответьте.

Comment: В этом значении можно сказать, что нечто "обесценено" вбросом (если намеренно) информации или публикацией случайно похожего.